# WordPress форма заявки с опросником

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Нашел сайт (https://zavod2kmo.ru/), нравится все как есть, хотел бы реализовать так же у себя на сайте WP.

Возможно, есть уже готовые решения или как лучше всего сделать?

Подскажите, кто сталкивался с данным вопросом.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Этот сайт не на WordPress

Comment: я знаю,просто реализация понравилась

Comment: @Ivan а в чем проблема написать самому ?

Comment: за те,деньги,которые дают)даже делать ничего не хочется)поэтому искал решение из коробки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отвечать на вопрос готовых решений, то они есть - достаточно в поиске набрать фразу "**wordpress multi step form**". Вот некоторые из вариантов:

- Multi Step Form - https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-step-form/
- Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms -
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

Но можно и самому написать данный функционал.